# Не работает border-image: linear-gradient в сафари

Tags: css

Не работает border-image: linear-gradient в сафари. Появляется просто черная полоска

```css
.about-block {
    padding: 67px 100px 0 120px;

    border-bottom: 3px solid;

    margin-bottom: 300px;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( to right, #fc5f45 25%, #38c695 25%, #38c695 50%, #b27cf5 50%, #b27cf5 75%, #feb960 75%) 5;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fc5f45 25%, #38c695 25%, #38c695 50%, #b27cf5 50%, #b27cf5 75%, #feb960 75%) 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-block">dsadasd</div>
```

Comment: это оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900796/css-border-image-gradient-not-working-in-safari-10

Comment: нет. Если делаю как там написано рамка становится просто черной